# How does >>= works in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How does this operator works in JavaScript . Found from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Non-native_methods

```
var s = 12;
s>>=1;
console.log( s );
s>>=1;
console.log( s );
s>>=1;
console.log( s );
```

I am getting result "6,3,1" . I am curious about it working .

Comment: Please read the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: How does it work? Or what does it do?

Comment: I think questions like this should be closed at once... and people are upvoting it. Should we reproduce the whole bloody documentation here or just teach people how to read it? I mean, should I ask a different question now about `<<=` or `>>>`?

Comment: @bažmegakapa - To be fair, `>>=` is a [Goolenope](http://googlenope.com/view.php), and MDN's search facility also didn't return anything useful. But yes, a search for "JavaScript operators" would have gotten there in the end.

Comment: @bažmegakapa: On one hand, at least OP found it while reading docs. On the other hand, why then didn't OP just read more docs?! :P

Comment: @nnnnnn That's it, not very complicated. Other than being easy, cheap rep for asker and answerers at the same time, this question is absolutely useless and promotes a bad practice...

Comment: @bažmegakapa surely that depends on the quality of the answer?  I've answered plenty of questions where the query is _superficially_ very similar to other questions, but where the devil was in the details.

Comment: Let's not forget the most important question... how to do this with jQuery? :D

Comment: @Alnitak Your answer is of course top notch, it deserves the upvotes. The question does not. I've seen better questions closed in minutes here.

Comment: @bažmegakapa I searched in Google to find answer for ` >>=  in javascript` & `<<=` .on my first search I could not find, real explanation like @Alnitak , and other answer `s = s >> 1` .And you are right, I will delete this question soon.

Comment: @rab Do not delete it now because Alnitak's answer is worth keeping - IMHO.

Comment: @bažmegakapa I could not delete `Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead`. I flagged for moderator to delete the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`>>=` performs a *bitwise* right binary shift, and assigns the result back to the left hand operand.

```
12      is 0b1100
12 >> 1 is 0b0110 (6)
 6 >> 1 is 0b0011 (3)
 3 >> 1 is 0b0001 (1)
```

Note that a single bit right shift is equivalent to an "integer divide by two" operation.

In JS, all bitwise operations (except for `>>>`) implicitly cast the left hand operand to a signed 32 bit number.  The `>>>` operation cases to an *unsigned* 32 bit number.

Comment: and you beat me to it ;) absolutely correct.

Comment: this is real good explanation .

Answer (score 6):

It a right shift operator. 
`12` in binary is `1100`, right shift by 1 position is `0110` which is `6`, right shift by 1 more position is `0011` and the last right shift gives you `0001`.

Comment: @PaulS. strictly speaking, a bitwise operation on _any_ type uses the JS internal `GetValue` operation.  This is not specific to `string` variables.

Comment: @Alnitak see step `5` [here](http://es5.github.io/#x11.7.2), it is using [`ToInt32`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.5)

Comment: @PaulS. yes, indeed, after calling `GetValue` at step 2, which _is not specific to string operands_.

Answer (score 3):

As other have noted, this is a [right shift operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

It is equal to writing

```
s = s >> 1
```

So it's mainly a shortcut.